# merge elements in forestplot format a single element

Tags: r, r-forestplot

I am creating a `forestplot` using the `forestplot` package in R, and am having trouble with a few things.

**Questions:**

1. Is it possible to merge two adjacent text elements
2. Is it possible to modify either a single text element font, or the font of an entire row

**My Code:**

```
library(forestplot)

# creating text
text <- rbind(c('', 'N (%)', 'SRT', 'ART',  'HR [95% CI]'),
              c('', '', '5 year survival %',  '5 year survival %', ''),
              c('Seminal Vesicle Involvement', '', '', '', ''),
              c('        Yes', '10 (20%)',   '94', '12', '0.73  [0.36, 1.50]'),
              c('        No', '40 (80%)',   '96', '10', '1.78  [0.73, 4.35]'),
              c('Gender', '', '', '', ''),
              c('        Male', '13 (22.5%)', '84', '22', '0.06  [-0.2, 0.86]'),
              c('        Female', '37 (77.5%)', '93', '13', '1.89  [0.90, 6.67]'))

# creating the plot
forestplot(text, 
           mean = c(NA, NA, NA, 0.73, 1.78, NA, 0.06, 1.89), 
           lower = c(NA, NA, NA, 0.36, 0.73, NA, -0.2, 0.90), 
           upper = c(NA, NA, NA, 1.50, 4.35, NA, 0.86, 6.67),
           is.summary=c(T, T, T, F, F, T, F, F),
           lineheight = unit(0.9, "cm"),
           graph.pos = 5,
           graphwidth = unit(4, 'cm'),
           xticks = c(-1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4),
           ci.vertices = T,
           txt_gp = fpTxtGp(ticks = gpar(cex = 1),
                            xlab  = gpar(cex = 1),
                            label = gpar(cex = 0.8),
                            summary = gpar(cex = 0.8)),
           col=fpColors(box="black", 
                        line="darkgrey", 
                        summary="black", 
                        zero='grey20', 
                        axes='grey20'),
           hrzl_lines = list("2" = gpar(lwd=1, col = "#000044")))
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Desired:**

I would like the two `5 year survival %` text bits to be combined into 1 (and centered between the two headings above), and either just those elements or the whole row to be italic font.

I have tried using `summary=list(gpar(...))` for the `txt_gp` option, but that only seems to be able to modify the whole column, and I have found nothing on merging cells at all.

Comment: "Combined" or "merging" operation is not well-defined. Mathematically? Adjacently?, and if adjacently, then with a comma separating them?, parentheses enclosing them? What exactly is needed? And what about the headers? (And there are no "cells". That's just not a term that makes sense in this context. R is not Excel.)

Comment: the headers I want to stay the way they are, its only the line with the words 5 year survival. I want there to only be one bit of text saying '5 year survival %', but have it appear half way between the two headings they are currently underneath. You're right, cells probably wasnt the best word to use, sorry. But the more I investigate this the less likely it seems it is possible to do what I want :(

Answer (score 1):

If you make the `colgap` much smaller in `forestplot` than usual, you can split the text that is currently duplicated in row 2 in columns 3 and 4 into two parts:

```
> text[2, 4] <- 'survival % '
> text[2, 3] <- '5 year '
> 
> forestplot(text, 
+            mean = c(NA, NA, NA, 0.73, 1.78, NA, 0.06, 1.89), 
+            lower = c(NA, NA, NA, 0.36, 0.73, NA, -0.2, 0.90), 
+            upper = c(NA, NA, NA, 1.50, 4.35, NA, 0.86, 6.67),
+            is.summary=c(T, T, T, F, F, T, F, F),
+            lineheight = unit(0.9, "cm"),
+            graph.pos = 5,
+            graphwidth = unit(4, 'cm'),
+            xticks = c(-1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4),
+            ci.vertices = T, 
#   add line---------
          colgap=unit(.0011,"npc"),
#
+            txt_gp = fpTxtGp(ticks = gpar(cex = 1),
+                             xlab  = gpar(cex = 1),
+                             label = gpar(cex = 0.8),
+                             summary = gpar(cex = 0.8)),
+            col=fpColors(box="black", 
+                         line="darkgrey", 
+                         summary="black", 
+                         zero='grey20', 
+                         axes='grey20'),
+            hrzl_lines = list("2" = gpar(lwd=1, col = "#000044")))
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for the solution. not perfect, but probably the best I'll get short of modifying it in paint :P